# How to push JSON kafka messages to bigquery table with column as JSON type using dataflow flex template?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

My Kafka-to-Bigquery dataflow job accepts kafka messages but while pushing it to bigquery is not mapping with bigquery schema.
My BQ schema is like

`"event: JSON"`

KafkaToBigquery code -

```
 PCollectionTuple convertedTableRows =
    pipeline
        /*
         * Step #1: Read messages in from Kafka
         */
        .apply(
            "ReadFromKafka",
            KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                .withConsumerConfigUpdates(props)
                .withBootstrapServers(bootstrapServers)
                .withTopics(topicsList)
                .withKeyDeserializerAndCoder(
                    StringDeserializer.class, NullableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
                .withValueDeserializerAndCoder(
                    StringDeserializer.class, NullableCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of()))
                .withoutMetadata())
        /*
         * Step #2: Transform the Kafka Messages into TableRows
         */
        .apply(
            "LogKafkaMessages", // Add this transform to log Kafka messages
            ParDo.of(
                new DoFn<KV<String, String>, KV<String, String>>() {
                  @ProcessElement
                  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                    KV<String, String> kafkaMessage = c.element();
                    LOG.error(
                        "Received Kafka Message - Key: "
                            + kafkaMessage.getKey()
                            + ", Value: "
                            + kafkaMessage.getValue());
                    c.output(kafkaMessage);
                  }
                }))
        .apply("ConvertMessageToTableRow", new MessageToTableRow(options));
LOG.error("Read from kafka");
LOG.error("Reading------", convertedTableRows);
/*
 * Step #3: Write the successful records out to BigQuery
 */
WriteResult writeResult =
    convertedTableRows
        .get(TRANSFORM_OUT)
        .apply(
            "WriteSuccessfulRecords",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                .withoutValidation()
                .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                .to(options.getOutputTableSpec()));

LOG.error("WriteSuccessfulRecords");
LOG.error("WriteSuccessfulRecords------", writeResult);
```

Problem Trying to solve here is to get events from kafka and parse them into JSON and then push it to event column (JSON format) in BigQuery.
Currently, it is looking for specific mapping of schema.
Tried these things with Test kafka message -

```
{"id":123, "data":"Hello"}
{"id":456, "data":{"sub":"World"}}
```

But it's looking for id or data or sub.
Tried adding UDF as well -

```
 function process(inJson) {
// Define the schema-compatible structure
var outputData = {
    event: inJson
};
var result = JSON.stringify(outputData);
// Return the JSON string
return result;}
```

tried giving it as "javascriptTextTransformGcsPath" while running flex template.
How can i make sure all events will be transformed and pushed to single JSON "event" column?